# How can I get the URL of an <a href="http://www.mysite.com"> in JavaScript?

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm processing some text in JavaScript (using Node, so please no jQuery). I want to extract all URL's that are in `<a>` tags on the page. How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArray = preg_match_all("<a.*?href=[\'|\"](.*?)[\'|\"]", "How can I get the URL of an <a href=\"http://www.mysite.com\"> in JavaScript? How can I get the URL of an <a href=\"http://www.mysite.org\"> in JavaScript?")

if ( myArray != null) {
  for ( i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) { 
    alert(myArray[i]);
  }
}

function preg_match_all(regex, haystack) {
   var globalRegex = new RegExp(regex, 'g');
   var globalMatch = haystack.match(globalRegex);
   matchArray = new Array();
   for (var i in globalMatch) {
      nonGlobalRegex = new RegExp(regex);
      nonGlobalMatch = globalMatch[i].match(nonGlobalRegex);
      matchArray.push(nonGlobalMatch[1]);
   }
   return matchArray;
}
```

preg_match_all function taken from http://coding.pressbin.com/16/Javascript-equivalent-of-PHPs-pregmatchall

I would recommend using an online tester such as this one: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Comment: What about single quotes around the href?

Comment: Then change them to [\"|\'] instead of \".

Comment: This returns the `<a href` as well. I just want te URL

Comment: Regular expression matches return an array containing matches. The element at position 0 is the entire match while, in this case, the element at position 1 is the url, hence the parentheses around the url.

Comment: My text is: `A link to <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> or maybe to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a> or perhaps to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> again?`... Your code returns: `longUrls[0] = <a href="http://www.google.com"
longUrls[1] = <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"
longUrls[2] = <a id="stuff" HREF='http://www.google.com'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that match doesn't work the same as PHP's preg_match_all. See the update.